# Javascript to access an Array in an Array with an input variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm developing a form that processes input information differently depending on the State the user is in. On my webpage I have a list of States in a drop down: 
`<div class="top-row" title="Select the proper state from the list.">
    <select name="state-list" class="state-list" id="stateList" >
        <option value=30>Select State</option>
        <option value=0>AL</option>
        <option value=1>AR</option>
        <option value=2>CA</option>
        <option value=3>CT</option>
        <option value=4>DE</option>
        <option value=5>DC</option>
        <option value=6>GA</option>
    </select>
</div>`

In my javascript file I made an array called states and placed the States as arrays:

```
var state = { AL: [false, true, true, 0], AZ: [false, false, false, 0],
AR: [false, true, true, 0], CA: [false, false, false, 0], 
CT: [false, true, true, 0], DE: [false, true, true, 0],
DC: [false, true, true, 0], GA: [false, true, true, 0]};
```

The problem I'm having is finding the array value. I've done a lot of searching, but I'm just not finding a solution.

```
findState = document.getElementById('stateList').value;
console.log(state.findState[0]);
```

They all return *undefined*, but 'findState' has a value. How can I access the values of the specific State's array within the state array?

Answer (score 4):

Your expression is trying to access the `findState` property on the `state` object, and it has no property named `findState`. Instead, use bracket notation:

```
console.log(state[findState][0]);
```

Also, don't forget to do proper null/undefined checks to account for the possibility that the value could not be found (e.g. if the user re-selects the first option in the dropdown).

Comment: I'm still getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.

Comment: That's because your `select` control will have the values 0, 1, 2, 3 (because that's what you provided in the `value=` attributes), while your `state` object has properties named AL, AZ, AR, etc. Can you change your `<option>` elements to use the state abbreviations instead of numbers?

Comment: Yah know, I had them set to the State values to begin with, but I couldn't get it to work; so I removed them all and set the values to numerical. I just tried your solution however, and it's working. Guess I didn't try `state[findState][0];` before. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't make an array (`[]`) called state, you made an object (`{}`) called state.

In it, each "state" abbreviation is the key & the array of true/false options is the value.

Objects make no guarantee about the order of their contents, so you can't search them by numeric index.
You can either rework `state` to actually be an Array of objects, or rework how you access the values.

`findState` isn't returning the expected value. You first need to check the selected index, then get either the `value` property (numeric value attr) or the text.

```
var stateList = document.getElementById('stateList'); //the whole list in the DOM
var selectedState = stateList.options[stateList.selectedIndex]; //whichever one is selected
var numericValue = selectedState.value //value='#'
var textAbbrev = selectedState.text //"AR" , "AZ", etc
```

With an object using the abbreviations as the "key" you want `.text`

```
var optionsArray = state.textAbbrev //should give you the entire array for selected state 
console.log(optionsArray[0]); //should show the 1st true/false value in the selected state's array.
```

Also, your HTML is missing "AZ".